# ArrayList doesn't work in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, arraylist

I'm using a new Thread to search for servers and not to make any lags in other classes such as Graphics, etc. And I've found out that `.add()` method of the servers ArrayList doesn't work, even `servers.size()` doesn't work in the new thread. Do you know what is happening and how to solve this problem?

```
ArrayList<String> findServers(int howMany){
    ArrayList<String> servers = new ArrayList<>();
    Main.chatGraphics.log("<font face='arial' color='yellow'>Searching for servers...</font>");
    Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setText("Wait...");
    Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setEnabled(false);
    new Thread(() -> {
        Socket newSocket;
        for (int i = 2; i < 254; i++){
            if (servers.size() >= howMany)
                break;
            try {
                newSocket = new Socket();
                InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1." + i, Main.DEFAULT_PORT);
                if (isa.isUnresolved())
                    continue;
                newSocket.connect(isa, 10);
                servers.add(newSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()); // DOESN'T WORK <<
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (servers.size() == 0) // DOESN'T WORK TOO <<
            Main.chatGraphics.log("<font face='arial' color='red'>No available servers</font>");

        Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setEnabled(true);
        Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setText("");
        Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.grabFocus();
    }).start();

    return servers;
}
```

Also, I have another problem with this code: `Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setText("Wait...")` doesn't work. The setText method doesn't work itself only in this method. I think it happens because `setEnabled(false)` method comes right after it, but I'm not sure. Can you help me with this one too?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please. You do know that 1) your servers variable should be `volatile`, and 2) that you're returning the servers variable before the thread has had a chance to do anything with it, that you shouldn't be returning it at all, but rather using it in a call-back mechanism, such as is available via a SwingWorker or with a Callable (not a Runnable).

Comment: Also this `Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setEnabled(true);` shouldn't be called within a background thread as it violates Swing threading rules. Again, use a SwingWorker and do things right. Please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By doesn't work I mean that servers.add() doesn't add anything to servers ArrayList and servers.size() == 0 gives false after using add() which didn't work, however if I print servers.size() to the console it gives 0.

Comment: If this were my code I'd separate this bit of code from the GUI and debug it separately. Divide and conquer. Once functioning I'd then try to mesh it into the GUI via a `SwingWorker<List<String>, Void>`, returning the list in the worker's `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: @Hovercraft you can't make it volatile. For one thing, you can only make fields volatile, not local variables. For another, this is effectively final, and you can't make something final and volatile.

Comment: @AndyTurner good point. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ty for solving setText() problem, I've put all the GUI commands in the new thread and everything started working.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see my SwingWorker answer below for example on a Swing thread-safe code solution.

Comment: `"I've put all the GUI commands in the new thread ..."` -- wait. No, don't do this. Again no GUI code should be called within a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted, your `List<String>` shouldn't even be exposed to multiple threads but rather should be local to the worker thread itself, and only used once the worker thread has completed its work. I suggest that you use a `SwingWorker<List<String>, Void>` -- a worker thread that will return the String list in a call back once it is done doing its job. All the background work is done within the worker's `doInBackground()` method, and no Swing code should be present within this method. The worker's `done()` method is called on the Swing event thread, and so Swing code can and should be present here. Something along these lines could work, but if they don't then you've likely got problems elsewhere in code not shown and need to do further debugging (code not compiled nor tested):

```
void findServers(int howMany) {
    // code run on the Swing event thread
    Main.chatGraphics.log("<font face='arial' color='yellow'>Searching for servers...</font>");
    Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setText("Wait...");
    Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setEnabled(false);

    // code run in background thread, that returns our List of interest
    new SwingWorker<List<String>, Void>() {

        @Override
        public List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {

            // the List should be declared local within the worker
            List<String> servers = new ArrayList<>();
            Socket newSocket;
            for (int i = 2; i < 254; i++) {
                if (servers.size() >= howMany) {
                    break;
                }

                // don't catch exceptions wihin the worker. Do this in the
                // done() method.
                newSocket = new Socket();
                InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1." + i,
                        Main.DEFAULT_PORT);
                if (isa.isUnresolved())
                    continue;
                newSocket.connect(isa, 10);
                servers.add(newSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            }
            return servers;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            try {
                // call the worker's get() method to retrieve the List
                // and to capture any exceptions
                List<String> servers = get();
                if (servers.size() == 0) {
                    Main.chatGraphics.log("<font face='arial' color='red'>No available servers</font>");
                }

                Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setEnabled(true);
                Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.setText("");
                Main.chatGraphics.msgInputTF.grabFocus();


                // *** use servers in the GUI **here**


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                // you will need more robust exception handling here
                // including extracting from this the true
                // underlying exception that was called
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Again for more on this, please read: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

The key to all of this is the following:

- the List again is local to the worker thread
- You get the List and start using it not as a direct return from a method (note that I declared findServers to be `void`), but within a call back, here the worker's `done()` method that runs only after the worker has completed its actions.
- Again take care to avoid making Swing calls from background threads.

Comment: Thank you so much, but again setText() doesn't work and I still need to catch errors in doInBackground() method, because if the done() method catches any then it just stops the further execution of code.

Comment: @nexusgeniuz: then you can do that -- handle the errors within the doInBackground, but do propagate any upstream if the GUI needs to handle it. As for `setText(...)` it will work if the code is wired correctly. That's another issue that will need to be solved. I stand by this answer and back it with years of experience in this field.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't recommend to put set(...) inside of doInBackground()? Everything works great when I do it.

Comment: @nexusgeniuz: if you mean `.setText(...)` because doing this means that you're making *mutational* Swing calls off of the Swing event thread. This will result in hard to debug *intermittent* exceptions to be thrown. Yes your code will work *sometimes* but other times it won't, and unreliable code is worse than no code at all. You really need to read the tutorial link that I've given you several times now. It explains all.

Comment: `"I mean how does it violate Swing threading rules?"`: Please understand that **Swing is not thread safe**. Again see [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Read [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) in particular.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc of `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
> ```

You have multiple threads which access this list concurrently: the thread calling the method and the newly created thread. The newly-created thread makes structural modifications (it adds to the list). Hence, you need external synchronization.

Wrap your `ArrayList` in a `synchronizedList`.

Comment: I've already tried to use synchronizedList but it didn't work too. I wrote it like this: List<String> servers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

Comment: I don't think that this will solve his problem. The ArrayList should be local to the Callable used by the thread and so won't really be used in separate threads, until the Callable is completely finished.